# Sorting vectors by increasing magnitude

Tags: c, sorting

For an exercise I need to sort vectors by their magnitude. As this is only my second time programming something, I find this really hard to do. 
This is my teacher's example:

**Input:**

The vector length n, followed by the vector count m; subsequently, the entries of each vector (one vector per line).

```
3 5    
4 4 4    
2 4 2    
1 1 9    
-1 -2 5    
1 1 1
```

**Output:**

The vectors, sorted by increasing magnitude (one per line). Use the %e formatting string to print the coordinates.

```
1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    
2.000000e+00 4.000000e+00 2.000000e+00    
-1.000000e+00 -2.000000e+00 5.000000e+00    
4.000000e+00 4.000000e+00 4.000000e+00    
1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 9.000000e+00
```

This is the code I've up to now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
int dim,num;
int i,j;
double **w, array[100];

scanf("%d %d ", &dim, &num); /*read N and M*/
w = calloc(num, sizeof (double*)); /*allocate array of M pointers*/
for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    /*allocate space for N dimensional vector */
    w[i] = calloc(dim, sizeof(double));
    /* read the vector */
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        scanf("%le",&w[i][j]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
  printf("\n%d", array[i]);
}

void swap ( double **p, double **q )
{
double *tmp ;

tmp = *p ;
*p = *q ;
*q = tmp ;
}

void bubble(int a[], int n) /* n is the size of a[] */
{
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    for (j = n - 1; j > i; --j)
        if (a[j-1] > a[j])
            swap(&a[j-1], &a[j]);


}
```

But it's not working, and I'm stuck. Is there someone that can help me?

Comment: Change your swap-condition to `fabs(current swap condition)`?

Comment: What is your definition of [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29) for a vector and where are you calculating that? Why your input is stored in `w` while you print out `array`?